# Flask - SubViews

Tags: python, flask

I am looking to use a certain design pattern in my application, but I am not sure if my pattern really even fits with Flask mechanisms. I am just verifying that I have not overlooked existing solutions.

I would like to have a top-level View that renders the response of another proxied request. The thing is, I am not proxying external URLs, but rather views from within my same application (kind of like Blueprints that depend on other Blueprints). Similar to the 'render_template()' function, I am looking for something like `render_view`, or even better, `*request_view_as_string*`. I then need to process the response and re-render.

I am using template inheritance to the best of my abilities (jinja2), but much of my difficulty is coming from lots of non-template processing in between the template blocks. I am still getting a feel for jinja, and my templates are starting to feel polluted with hacks.

---

## Edit

Basically, I misunderstood the role of jinja. My application needs to build heavier on jinja. I kept trying to get in and out of jinja as quickly as possible, and that is where my nested dependencies were starting to cause problems. Ultimately, most of the features I needed for my "subviews" was built right into Jinja, I just wasn't sure how to properly integrate them with FLask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, Jinja2 supports [`macros`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#macros), which let you share functionality between templates:

```
{# helpers.jinja #}
{% macro generate_select(itrbl) %}
    <select{{kwargs|xmlattrs}}>
    {% for item in itrbl %}
        <option value="{{item.value}}">{{item.text}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
{% endmacro %}

{# page1.jinja #}
{% import "helpers.jinja" as helpers %}
{{ helpers.generate_select(data, name="my_data_field") }}
```

For more complicated bits of functionality (A / B testing, loading different features depending on what the user's account has enabled, etc.) [`extends`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#extends), [`include`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include), and [`import`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#import) can take variable values:

```
{# A custom template with a *lot* of hooks #}
{% extends base_template %}
{% import custom_functionality_provider as provider %}
{% block common_name %}
    {% if features.feature_x %}
        {% include feature_x_include %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ provider.operation() }}
{% endblock common_name %}
```

---

```
@app.route("/some-route")
def some_route():
    # Of course, in real life you would determine these values
    # on the basis of user / condition lookups, rather than
    # hardcoding values in your render_template call
    render_template("custom.jinja", base_template="AB/A/base.jinja",
        custom_functionality_provider="macros/lowcostplan.jinja",
        feature_x_include="AB/A/features/feature_x.jinja",
        features=some_features_object)
```

Finally, you can pass callables that return strings to any Jinja template, giving you access to the full power of Python:

```
def custom_implimentation_a(**context_args):
    return render_template("template_a.jinja", **context_args)

def custom_implimentation_b(**context_args):
    return render_template("template_b.jinja", **context_args)

@app.route("/some-route")
def some_route():
    if condition:
        provider = custom_implimentation_a  # Note, no parenthesis
    else:
        provider = custom_implimentation_b

    return render_template("some_page.jinja", provider=provider)
```

Comment: You clarified many things, especially my understanding of 'render_template', which essentially is the 'view' mechanism I sought.

Comment: When you referred to "AB/A/features/feature_x.jinja", I imagine that would be found in a deeply nested templates folder, Or does Flask build a 'global' template namespace, including blueprints, that just magically finds the right template? If *feature_x* was sizeable, could you move this "feature" to a separate BluePrint, yet still access it in the manner you demonstrated above?

Comment: @user2097818 - indeed, I was assuming a deeply nested template folder structure.  Flask *does* combine all of the blueprint template folders into the global template namespace though, so you can override blueprint templates at the application level.  (So yes, you could move `feature_x` from blueprint to blueprint and as long as the *template* path stayed the same it would still be addressable).

Answer (score 0):

I do consider Sean's first answer as the most appropriate, but I did run across this little mechanism for those times when Jinja is making Python tasks a bit difficult.

http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/local/

This should be a little more productive than Flask's g variable. See also a slightly different usage (when one global 'namespace' is no longer manageable)

http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/13/

I very often forget that Flask and Werkzeug are related projects. The huge benefit of this is that much of their functionality does not overlap with the other project.

When you are newbie approaching from the Flask side, if you feel like Flask is missing a few gears, there is a good chance its because they already included them in Werkzeug.